# Como quitar variables repetidas en un array JS

Tags: javascript

Hola amigos tengo el siguiente array

> var bdn = ["15", "11", "13", "15", "15"];

Y necesito quitar los números o caracteres que se repitan. Para obtener algo como esto:

```
["15","11","13"]
```

Alguien sabe como puedo hacer esto en JS?

Comment: ¿qué has intentado?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set#Remove_duplicate_elements_from_the_array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes hacerlo así:

```js
var bdn = ["15", "11", "13", "15", "15"];
var n = bdn.length;
var array_final = [];

for(var i=0;i<n;i++){
  if($.inArray(bdn[i],array_final) == -1){
    array_final.push(bdn[i]);
  }
}

console.log(array_final);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Lo que hacemos es declarar un array vacio (array_final) e ir recorriendo el array inicial de números (con repeticiones).

Dentro del bucle se hace la comprobación para saber si el valor del array inicial está incluido dentro del array final. Si no lo está, lo incluimos (y si lo está no hacemos nada).

Finalmente tendrás tu array con números y sin repeticiones.

Espero que te sirva.

Answer (score 0):

Podrias usar esto.

```
console.log( bdn.filter((v, i, a) => a.indexOf(v) === i) )
```

Comment: Una explicación a tu código ayudaría a elevar su calidad, por favor lee [answer]